# I promised/offered her to send the money right away

Tags: infinitives, reported-speech, indirect-objects

Page 632 of Collins English Usage reads

> When you are reporting an action that the speaker intends to perform,
> you can sometimes use either a 'to'-infinitive or a 'that'-clause.
>
> You do not use a 'to'-infinitive if the hearer is being mentioned, *I
> **promise**d her I would send her the money.*

Are sentences such as *I promised/offered **her** to send the money rightaway* grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I would spell it "right away".

Comment: offered her to send and promised her to send are not grammatical in English. I offered her a drink. I promised her a rose garden. Rather than trying to catch out good references, concentrate on internalizing them.

Comment: @Lambie what's the linguistic term for verbs behaving as such?

Comment: offer and promise are transitive verbs. and take direct objects. And, fyi, it's better to say: verbs behaving like this or like that or as these do.

Comment: @Lambie monotransitive? Secondly, how about _...verbs so behaving_?

Comment: No, it sounds more English to say: verbs behaving this way.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.lieder.net/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=25695: "He promised me at parting / to meet me at springtime here." So it could be used, but gives an antiquated tone. As Collins suggests, either "I promised to send the money..." or "I promised her I would send the money..." would be more idiomatic.